# Tengo 2 arrays de objetos y busco fusionar propiedades de uno en otro Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, json, objeto

Tengo un json con los datos de los cursos y necesito agregarle el centro donde se dictan los cursos, pero un curso tiene muchos centros y por cada objeto se me ocurre hacer una copia del objeto cursos pero no se como hacerlo.

```
cursos = 
[{ id": 9631,
    "post_title": "Futbol",
    "post_status": "publish,
     barrios": "Parque Patricios",
    "duracion": "Cuatrimestral",
    "turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche"},
{ id": 9637,
    "post_title": "Voley",
    "post_status": "publish,
     barrios": "Pompeya",
    "duracion": "Cuatrimestral",
    "turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche"}]

sede = [
  { Ids: '9631', Nombre: 'Centro Nº 04' },
  {  Ids: '9631', Nombre: 'Centro Nº 05' },   
  {  Ids: '9631', Nombre: 'Centro Nº 07' }, 
  {  Ids: '9637', Nombre: 'Centro Nº 15' }
]
```

Estoy tratando de que la informacion me quede asi

```
cursos = [{ id": 9631,
    "post_title": "Futbol",
    "post_status": "publish,
     barrios": "Parque Patricios",
    "duracion": "Cuatrimestral",
    "turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche",
     Nombre: 'Centro Nº 04'
    },{ id": 9631,
    "post_title": "Futbol",
    "post_status": "publish,
     barrios": "Parque Patricios",
    "duracion": "Cuatrimestral",
    "turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche",
     Nombre: 'Centro Nº 05'
     },{ id": 9631,
    "post_title": "Futbol",
    "post_status": "publish,
     barrios": "Parque Patricios",
    "duracion": "Cuatrimestral",
    "turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche",
     Nombre: 'Centro Nº 07'
     },{ id": 9637,
    "post_title": "Voley",
    "post_status": "publish,
     barrios": "Pompeya",
    "duracion": "Cuatrimestral",
    "turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche",
     Nombre: 'Centro Nº 15'
    }
    ]
```

Pero no lo estoy logrando, agradezco cualquier ayuda o idea que pueda probar.

Comment: Si no muestras lo que has intentado en tu pregunta poco podremos ayudarte. No hacemos el código a medida, sino que solucionamos problemas que no sabeis resolver, pero tu ahora mismo no has planteado ningun problema, tan solo has pedido que lo hagamos, por eso debes incluir lo que has hecho para que la pregunta sea válida. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example], gracias

Comment: Gracias masterguru solo estoy pidiendo ideas, no la solucion. No puse los codigos que probe porque no me deja formular la pregunta con tanto codigo. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Mira, si lo que buscas en una idea, podrías transformar tus `JSON` en objetos Javascript:

```
let cursos = '[{ "id": "9631","post_title": "Futbol","post_status": "publish","barrios": "Parque Patricios","duracion": "Cuatrimestral","turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche"},'
+ '{"id": "9637","post_title": "Voley","post_status": "publish","barrios": "Pompeya","duracion": "Cuatrimestral","turnos": "Mañana, Tarde, Noche"}]';

let sede = '[{"Ids":"9631","Nombre":"Centro Nº 04"},{"Ids":"9631","Nombre":"Centro Nº 05"},'
+ '{"Ids":"9631","Nombre":"Centro Nº 07"},{"Ids":"9637","Nombre":"Centro Nº 15"}]';

let objCursos = JSON.parse(cursos);
let objSede = JSON.parse(sede);
```

Una vez hecho esto ya podrás trabajar con ellos de forma más cómoda y añadirles otros elementos, por ejemplo:

```
for (var item in objCursos){

    //Aquí realizas una búsqueda de todos aquellos elementos 
    //en el objSede cuyo ids === objCursos[item].id
    //Luego puedes hacer la asignación de forma similar a:

    objCursos[item].Nombre = objSede[item].Nombre;
}
```

Creo que la línea de lo que búscas debería ir por allí.

Comment: Gracias T.S.D.  esta linea de codigo lo cambia todo let objCursos = JSON.parse(cursos);

Comment: ¡Un placer poder ayudar!